# Which are the funding options for a Postdoc in Denmark?

Tags: funding, postdocs, denmark

I am willing to apply for a position in Denmark at Copenhagen university. However, the putative PI told me that has no money to fund a postdoc position and recommended some fellowship options to apply. (Curie and Lundbeck). I come from Argentina and European calls are out of my range.

I would like to know if there are other options to obtain funding to do a postdoc in Denmark.

Comment: I don't understand the close votes. Would this be considered off topic if it were about research funding open to foreigners in the US?

Comment: Some funding opportunities are only available if you apply for positions in some countries or continent.

Comment: @henning probably because this is a question that is 1) specific to one person or at least few, and also as it could be solved by research by the OP...

Comment: Similar question for Germany and Switzerland: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55455/postdoc-funding-for-an-american-looking-to-do-a-postdoc-in-europe-in-theoretica

Comment: Similar question for USA: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/45791/are-there-post-doc-grants-available-for-non-us-citizens-in-the-us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At DTU there are two postdoc programmes, Eurotech and H.C. Ørsted:

- https://www.dtu.dk/english/research/research-at-dtu/postdoc-programmes/eurotech-cofund-postdoc
- https://www.dtu.dk/english/research/research-at-dtu/postdoc-programmes/h-c-oersted-cofund-postdoc

More generally you might want to search for postdoc programmes specific to the university you would like to go to. Also ask your contact at the university for guidelines.

Last year the funding opportunities from Danish institute for independent research were mostly targeted at more established researchers, but maybe still worth checking out: https://dff.dk/en/application/overview-of-instruments

I do not recall Denmark having plenty of general postdoc funding opportunities. Life sciences might be more generous than other fields. You will not know if the European ones are out of your league without trying.

Comment: If you are willing to specify the university, that will allow more targeted answers. (Also, you can upvote or accept answers you found useful.)

Comment: I´m yet learning how to use the forum. Thanks a lot for the advice. I was hoping to get funding for the Copenhagen University.